# I want conditional formatting to turn the cell green if it is < or = 1.99% of the lowest value in the range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I’m using Google Sheets.

First, I want conditional formatting to find the lowest value in a range. I've done this by entering "=G3=min($G3:$N3)" for the custom formula.

After that, I want conditional formatting to turn the cell green if it is < or = 1.99% of the lowest value in the range.

I also want conditional formatting to turn the cell red if it is 2% or greater than the lowest value in the range.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What web application are you using?

Comment: I believe there is an error in the question ... if the minimum of the range was 10, which cells should turn green?

Answer (score 1):

If the cells should turn green if their value is <= minimum of the range PLUS a value between 0 and 1.99% of that value, the formula is:

```
=and(G3:N3<>"",G3:N3<=101.99/100*min ($G3:$N3))
```

if they have to turn red, the formula is:

```
=and(G3:N3<>"",G3:N3>=102/100*min ($G3:$N3))
```

no color if the cell is empty

[image: colors]